# HTML/CSS Plotly plot size

Tags: html, css, graph, size

I have been attempting to construct a simple display for a couple of charts made with plotly. Using the useful embedding tools plotly provides, I have been able to get all plots on the webpage. (fairly simple)

Example of a chart to embed:

```html
<div class="graph-container">
<div class="left" margin-bottom = "3vh">
 <a href="https://plot.ly/~WillemvanderSpek/11/" target="_blank" title="data_month" style="display: block; text-align: center;"><img src="https://plot.ly/~WillemvanderSpek/11.png" alt="data_month" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://plot.ly/404.png';" /></a>
 <script data-plotly="WillemvanderSpek:11" src="https://plot.ly/embed.js" async></script>
</div>

<div class="right", margin-bottom = "3vh">
 <a href="https://plot.ly/~jorisdh/6/?share_key=hHbxuR1CeSgxuCuc0jspKz" target="_blank" title="n_deaths_state" style="display: block; text-align: center;"><img src="https://plot.ly/~jorisdh/6.png?share_key=hHbxuR1CeSgxuCuc0jspKz" alt="n_deaths_state" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://plot.ly/404.png';" /></a>
 <script data-plotly="jorisdh:6" sharekey-plotly="hHbxuR1CeSgxuCuc0jspKz" src="https://plot.ly/embed.js" async></script>
</div>

<div class="left", margin-bottom = "3vh">
 <a href="https://plot.ly/~WillemvanderSpek/2/" target="_blank" title="participant_relationships" style="display: block; text-align: center;"><img src="https://plot.ly/~WillemvanderSpek/2.png" alt="participant_relationships" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://plot.ly/404.png';" /></a>
 <script data-plotly="WillemvanderSpek:2" src="https://plot.ly/embed.js" async></script>
</div>

<div class="right", margin-bottom = "3vh">
 <a href="https://plot.ly/~voetbalsil/0/" target="_blank" title="d3-cloropleth-map"><img src="https://plot.ly/~voetbalsil/0.png" alt="d3-cloropleth-map" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://plot.ly/404.png';" /></a>
 <script data-plotly="voetbalsil:0" src="https://plot.ly/embed.js" async></script>
</div>

<div class="left", margin-bottom = "3vh">
 <a href="https://plot.ly/~BramBakker/8/" target="_blank" title="stacked-bar-demographics" style="display: block; text-align: center;"><img src="https://plot.ly/~BramBakker/8.png" alt="stacked-bar-demographics" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://plot.ly/404.png';" /></a>
 <script data-plotly="BramBakker:8" src="https://plot.ly/embed.js" async></script>
</div>

<div class="right">
 <a href="https://plot.ly/~voetbalsil/12/" target="_blank" title="Gun law strength" style="display: block; text-align: center;"><img src="https://plot.ly/~voetbalsil/12.png" alt="Gun law strength" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://plot.ly/404.png';" /></a>
 <script data-plotly="voetbalsil:12" src="https://plot.ly/embed.js" async></script>
</div>
</div>
```

Now how would I be able to set the size of these charts, and make them "sit" next to each other? I have tried using div-sizes in a separate CSS-file, and tried to change size locally. Finally, I've also tried a grid in order to line the graphs up, but they just end up overlapping.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

[image: Graphs]

Comment: In snippet you placed only one chart, so it doesn't show your problem with styling many of them (and placing next to each other). Could you please provide an example showing your problem?

Comment: @AndrzejZiółek Hi! Thanks for your response. I've added the (current) list of graphs. I've tried, as mentioned beforehand, to use gridview, hence the nested divs. Added a screenshot of the current situation. Please note that I am working on an ultrawide screen, so the image is a bit wider than usual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for clarification in comments.

> 'make them "sit" next to each other

Based on classes names you used (`.left`, `.right`) I assume you want these graphs to be in two columns and hope that below approach solves your problem.

```
.graph-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}
```

`display: flex` ensures equal distribution of space between all children (`.graph`), while `flex-wrap: wrap` makes them wrap when necessary.

```
.graph {
  width: 50%;
}

.graph img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

`width: 50%` for `.graph` gives each of them 50% of container width, while `width: 100%` for inside images ensures that images generated in graphs don't expand over it's parent's (`.graph)` size.

If you would like to learn more about `display: flex` I highly recommend you [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.graph-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.graph {
  width: 50%;
}

.graph img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="graph-container">
  <div class="graph left" margin-bottom="3vh">
    <a href="https://plot.ly/~WillemvanderSpek/11/" target="_blank" title="data_month" style="display: block; text-align: center;"><img src="https://plot.ly/~WillemvanderSpek/11.png" alt="data_month" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://plot.ly/404.png';" /></a>
    <script data-plotly="WillemvanderSpek:11" src="https://plot.ly/embed.js" async></script>
  </div>

  <div class="graph right" , margin-bottom="3vh">
    <a href="https://plot.ly/~jorisdh/6/?share_key=hHbxuR1CeSgxuCuc0jspKz" target="_blank" title="n_deaths_state" style="display: block; text-align: center;"><img src="https://plot.ly/~jorisdh/6.png?share_key=hHbxuR1CeSgxuCuc0jspKz" alt="n_deaths_state" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://plot.ly/404.png';" /></a>
    <script data-plotly="jorisdh:6" sharekey-plotly="hHbxuR1CeSgxuCuc0jspKz" src="https://plot.ly/embed.js" async></script>
  </div>

  <div class="graph left" , margin-bottom="3vh">
    <a href="https://plot.ly/~WillemvanderSpek/2/" target="_blank" title="participant_relationships" style="display: block; text-align: center;"><img src="https://plot.ly/~WillemvanderSpek/2.png" alt="participant_relationships" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://plot.ly/404.png';" /></a>
    <script data-plotly="WillemvanderSpek:2" src="https://plot.ly/embed.js" async></script>
  </div>

  <div class="graph right" , margin-bottom="3vh">
    <a href="https://plot.ly/~voetbalsil/0/" target="_blank" title="d3-cloropleth-map"><img src="https://plot.ly/~voetbalsil/0.png" alt="d3-cloropleth-map" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://plot.ly/404.png';" /></a>
    <script data-plotly="voetbalsil:0" src="https://plot.ly/embed.js" async></script>
  </div>

  <div class="graph left" , margin-bottom="3vh">
    <a href="https://plot.ly/~BramBakker/8/" target="_blank" title="stacked-bar-demographics" style="display: block; text-align: center;"><img src="https://plot.ly/~BramBakker/8.png" alt="stacked-bar-demographics" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://plot.ly/404.png';" /></a>
    <script data-plotly="BramBakker:8" src="https://plot.ly/embed.js" async></script>
  </div>

  <div class="graph right">
    <a href="https://plot.ly/~voetbalsil/12/" target="_blank" title="Gun law strength" style="display: block; text-align: center;"><img src="https://plot.ly/~voetbalsil/12.png" alt="Gun law strength" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://plot.ly/404.png';" /></a>
    <script data-plotly="voetbalsil:12" src="https://plot.ly/embed.js" async></script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thank you for the effort.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help. :). Remember you can also vote up my answer and don't hesitate to ask again if you will have any questions.

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." Would if I could. :)